# JavaScriptSerializer with named tuples

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

If I use [JavaScriptSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8) with named tuples I get following:

```
var serialized = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize((Foo: "Fooo", Bar: "Bar"));
```

serialized is:

> {"Item1":"F","Item2":"B"}

Any option to get:

> {"Foo":"F","Bar":"B"}

without writing custom class with properties Foo and Bar instead of tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try an anonymous class?

```
var serialized = new JavaScriptSerializer().SerializeObject(new {Foo= "Fooo", Bar= "Bar"});
```

It won't work with tuples because:

```
public void M() {
    var t = (Foo:"fooo",Bar:"Baar");
}
```

in IL is replaced by:

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void M () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 19 (0x13)
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
        [0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.ValueTuple`2<string, string>
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldloca.s 0
    IL_0003: ldstr "fooo"
    IL_0008: ldstr "Baar"
    IL_000d: call instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.ValueTuple`2<string, string>::.ctor(!0, !1)
    IL_0012: ret
} // end of method C::M
```

As you can see the name of the fields has disappeared from IL and can't be retrieved by any mean (it's just syntactic sugar)

Comment: Excellent idea, it will produce desired JSON, although it is not suitable for my problem. But as I did't explicitly state that I need to keep the tuple I will accept this if no other solution comes out :)

Comment: I updated my answer to detail why I think you won't get anything better by using tuples

Comment: Nice, forgot that named tuples are just sugar :)